# Backend Image creation and loading in webpage

Tags: asp.net

I am running into a problem here, and I have no code needed or that requires debugging. I'm looking for more of an idea to solve this issue, so here it is.

I have a *.exe that is a command prompt utility that generates images. What I am doing is using this utility for my asp.net website. In the background I do processing for each date in a asp.net calendar. If the image doesn't exist in the images directory for that date, Calendar_DayRender calls the backend to use the exe via Process. The image creation works great. As does the loading, if the image was already created in a previous session by any other user.

The problem is that the images are being created too quicky and I cannot load the image because when I try to add the Image to the cell, it wasn't created quickly enough. Any ideas on how I can solve this timing issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an optimal solution since it will block your thread.

However if you want to do this return only when the rendering is complete :

```
var process = Process.Start(...);
process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: I have tried the exact same thing and it still returns the results I have mention in the OP. I can create and load up to 31 images.

Comment: @bigjfunk am I correct in assuming you are running this code in Page load?

Comment: The image creation is done in a different class. The loading is done in the Calendar_DayRender for each cell(day). If an image doesn't exist for that cell, the creation class is called and the image is created by the exe.

Comment: @bigjfunk tried breakpoints to make sure the execution is serial instead of parallel? Perhaps write to a log to see the order of execution. Because if you `WaitForExit` the image should be there when the function returns.

Comment: I have done log writing. is called first createCalendarImage() then loadingImage() is called

Comment: @bigjfunk and `createCalendarImage()` contains `WaitForExit`?

Comment: hmm... I changed nothing, but added a File.Exists(createdImage) in the _DayRender after the image is created.. works fine now. I'm concered that I just bought it an extra second or so and that was enough but that under heavy server load it will do the same thing. what do you think?

Comment: yes, var process = Process.Start(pSI);
            
            process.WaitForExit();

Comment: `File.Exists` should be *much* faster than a few seconds. So I suspect its more than a timing issue. Probably the non existent files are skipped in this case